# How to know which keywords convert into goals

Tags: google-analytics, keyword, goal-tracking

I have set up goals in Google Analytics. Also, I have merged Adwords and Analytics. At the moment I can see sources, but I can't see the exact keywords which made conversion.

Comment: Questions about Google Analytics are off topic on StackOverflow but could be asked at the webmasters site.

Comment: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/74194/how-can-i-see-a-list-of-keywords-with-goal-progress-for-each

Answer (score 4):

Create a custom report.

1. Click the Custom Reporting button in the orange nav bar.
2. Click the Add a New Report button.
3. Select the metrics you want to see.
4. Select source as the first dimension and Keyword as the second dimension.
5. Click Save.

You'll be viewing information by keyword.

Comment: There is no orange nav bar in Google Analytics. And when I click on Reporting in the Nav bar, there is not button "add a new report"